# И худой Ермил, да богомил; а и хороший Влас, да подальше нас

Tags: пословицы

У Даля приведена вот такая пословица. Каков её смысл? Насколько я понял, имеется в виду, что Ермил, несмотря на свою худость (видимо, скверное поведение), в душе добрый (богоугодный), а вот Влас, который на первый взгляд хороший, нет. Но почему про первого говорят, что он (условно) *близок (мил) Богу*, а про второго — «подальше от нас (а не от Бога)»?

Answer (score 1):

**И худой Ермил, да богомил; а и хороший Влас, да подальше нас.**

Я эту пословицу понимаю так.

И худой Ермил, да богу мил; а и хороший Влас, да подальше нас (от Бога).

Мы  составляем мнение о людях: этот плох, а тот хорош, **но насколько оно верное?**

Богу виднее внутренний мир человека, поэтому он может судить иначе.

**Ему мил наш  "худой" Ермил, а вот наш "хороший" Влас не мил вовсе,** он самый последний у Бога на счету, то есть дальше, чем  все остальные, в том числе "мы".

Возможно, мы просто не заметили, что хороший (по нашему мнению) человек на самом деле двуличен и лицемерен.

Я не уверена, что мое мнение разделяет кто-нибудь еще, так как даже тематика этой пословицы определяется как-то странно (друг и недруг, например).

Comment: Sharon, предположение, что имелось в виду *подальше нас от Бога*, мне представляется разумным. Тогда назидательный посыл заключается, видимо, в том, что не следует превозносить внешне благочестивых людей, которые на поверку могут оказаться просто лицемерами (ср. *По бороде апостол, а по зубам собака*), согласны?

Answer (score 1):

*И худой Ермил, да богомил; а и хороший Влас, да подальше нас.*

Многие пословицы Даля своеобразны. Чаще употреблялась пословица в другом виде: *И худой Ермил, да богомил, а хороший Влас не хуже нас*(все люди равны перед Богом, какой бы веры ни были - богомилы старой веры или молящиеся деревянным иконам). 
Нужно знать, кто такой **богомил.**

По Далю, изучавшему духовный мир русского народа, Россия была в 19 веке полна иконоборцев. К ним Даль относил множество раскольничьих групп, а также хлыстов, духоборов, молокан и богомилов. Все иконоборческие христиане выступали против икон и служения в виде российской имперской военной службы. По Далю, эти группы прямо происходят от болгарских богомилов времён древних болгарских царей (Аспаруха, Асеней и т. д.). https://studopedia.su/19_139858_o-bogomilah.html

Даль считал, что именно **Евангельские Христианские** идеалы были близки русскому народу, от которого страшно далека была официальная военно-феодальная имперская ортодоксия.

Приводимая Далем пословица "И худой Ермил, да богомил; а и хороший Влас, да подальше нас" как раз и говорит, что **худой**(тощий, потому что богомилы проповедовали аскетизм, среди них толстых не было) **народу близок, хоть и гоним ортодоксальной Церковью, а вот Влас хороший для государственной религии, а от народа далёк.** Имя "Влас" здесь является эвфемизмом слова "Спас", то есть "деревянная икона".

Comment: Вопросы возникают следующие: 1) Это очень конкретное толкование пословицы взято из какого источника? 2) Даль: http://www.rodon.org/dvi/prn0.htm  У него пословицы разделены по темам. В какой теме эта пословица? 3)  Как выбрано имя Ермил, только для рифмы? Почему тогда Влас является эвфемизмом слова "Спас" 3) Получается, что эта пословица прямо призывает к раскольничеству? 4) Подальше нас...Какое толкование: "подальше нас от"  или "подальше от нас"? Что случилось с предлогом, почему он не обозначен? Ведь он очень важен для понимания смысла.

Comment: «Россия была в 19 веке полна иконоборцев»? С чего бы это? Если и были недоразумения, то только на предмет отказа от резных икон, т. е. деревянной сакральной скульптуры в храмах, как исключения намёка на использование истуканов ранними язычниками. Ну а фраза «Все иконоборческие христиане выступали против икон и служения в виде российской имперской военной службы» — полная неразбериха. Вами пропущено слово, но и оно смысла фразе не вернёт.

Comment: shampar, об этом много свидетельств, вот, например, факты из работы по истории : "https://arzamas.academy/mag/377-sekti
К концу XIX века количество скопцов составляло десятки тысяч человек. Правительство активно боролось с сектантами,  ссылая в Закавказье и Восточную Сибирь, где они создавали свои поселения и успешно хозяйствовали, всячески процветая.", "К концу XVIII в. движение молокан 
 насчитывало уже несколько тысяч человек. В 1805 году Александр I издал указ, согласно которому молоканам было разрешено открыто исповедовать свою веру. Но при  Николае I молокан начали преследовать "
 "

Comment: "После обрушившихся на духоборов правительственных репрессий за них вступился Лев Толстой. Он призвал Нобелевский комитет вручить духоборам премию мира и пожертвовал им часть гонорара за роман «Воскресение». Благодаря этой помощи более семи тысяч духоборов в самом начале ХХ века перебрались в Канаду, где их потомки живут до сих пор. Часть духоборов осталась в Грузии, однако после распада Советского Союза многие предпочли переехать в Россию. Таким образом в 90-х годах ХХ века в Тульской, Брянской и других областях появились духоборческие поселения.

Comment: Sharon, не собираюсь писать научную работу по этой пословице, тема указана: "друг-недруг", по смыслу подходит: "плох, да свой человек, хорош, да далёк, т.е. чужой", использовали эту пословицу все, кому она близка.  Даль  изучал секты, когда работал в министерстве внутренних дел и писал работу о скопцах, она осталась в Чертковской библиотеке.Он привёл эту пословицу как пример в своём словаре в статье к слову  БОГОДВИЖИМЫЙ -  Бого(у)мил,  собир. угасший раскольничий толк; богомилы явились в Болгарии, еще при царях, в связи с арианами.   https://slovar.cc/rus/dal/538832.html

Comment: В его сборнике помещены все пословицы, им услышанные, без разбора, поэтому Корф писал в отзыве, что в пословицах, народом созданных,«множество лжеучений и вредных начал», «опасных для нашего народа». Протоиерей Кочетовский заявил, что Далев труд есть «памятник народных глупостей». Даль ни к чему не призывал, только фиксировал факты народной жизни. На титульном листе, под заголовком, он поставил: «Пословица несудима». Вот давайте и не будем судить то, что мы не понимаем, не принимаем и т.д. Если это было в жизни народа - значит было.

Comment: А предлог не обозначен, потому что это народный говор - диалект, один из признаков диалектов - своеобразное употребление беспредложных сочетаний.

Comment: Людмила, я правильно понял, что пословицу «И худой Ермил, да богомил; а и хороший Влас, да подальше нас» Вы толкуете как «плох, да свой человек, хорош, да чужой», а пословицу «И худой Ермил, да богомил, а хороший Влас не хуже нас» как «все люди равны перед Богом»?

Comment: Правильно. Интересно, что на одном форуме мне попалось такое же понимание: некий  Валентин под фразой "На своей земле чужие почвоведы не нужны" привёл как пример пословицу:  И худой Ермил, да богомил; а  хороший Влас, да подальше бы от нас.
 http://www.ymuhin.ru/node/1001/replika-chem-vy-udovletvoreny%3Fpage=6?page=8 " Бы от" - это уже творчество, но при использовании пословиц оно не запрещается.

Answer (score 0):

От бытовой «И худой живот, да хлеб жует» эту пословицу отличает взгляд на человека как на личность. Всем хороший, но без царя в голове, симпатичный парень (не друг и не враг) не может привлекать людей так, как тот, пусть и невзрачный, но богобоязненный, кто утвердился в своей вере и принял по своим силам и годам груз заботы о других.

Comment: А как вы понимаете сочетание "подальше нас", что оно дословно означает? Это "подальше, чем мы" или "подальше от нас"? И если это второй вариант,  то почему убрали предлог ОТ?

Comment: "Подальше нас" — как понимаю — «Боже упаси», или «избави нас». Вариант с предлогом мне не встречался.

Comment: Мне это не кажется убедительным. Предлог ОТ еще мог со временем затеряться, но вот выражение "подальше нас" выглядит в таком толковании странным.

Comment: Предлог меняет ритм, что не в характере строя пословиц.

Comment: Но зачем же считать человека хорошим и тут же призывать держаться от него подальше? Где логика? В общем, загадочная пословица, хорошо  бы найти ее "научное" толкование.

Comment: «Ну ты хорош!», — есть же такое в обиходе... Хорош — слово с подтекстом.

Comment: Ирония и антифразис? Но тогда и "худой" в таком же положении. Кто-то смотрит со стороны и иронизирует  над  общепринятым мнением. Но концовка всё равно непонятна. И еще вопрос по поводу союза (частицы) И:  он-то что здесь обозначает?

Comment: Усиливает и обобщает до нарицательного значения.

Comment: Да, интересно, надо будет еще поработать над темой.

Comment: Появилась новая версия: и тот, и другой — почитаемые священномученики — Ермил и Власий, дни памяти которых соотв. 13/26 января и 11/24 февраля. Так Власий получается «подальше». Т. е. смысл может быть в сроках начала/окончания каких-то работ?

Comment: shampar, Вы думаете, что в пословице, по сути, говорится следующее: «Плохой Ермил, да Богу мил, а от хорошего Власа упаси Господь»? Подход иной, но смысл такой же, какой предложила Sharon.

Comment: Ермил не плох и не хорош: он незаметный трудяга — помощник и молитвенник, истово молится Богу «о нас о грешных»: вторая часть слова — богомил — от Милование = моление, просьба / милися дею = умиленно молюся.  Этим он близок всем. Думаю, что связывать болгарина X в. Богомила с ним, а имена Мучеников Ермила и Стратоника давно чтимы у нас, как последователя-еретика было бы неверно.